# Prestashop currentLocale is null in module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

When I try to call in my module `Context::getContext()->currentLocale->formatPrice($price, $currency);` or `$this->context->currentLocale->formatPrice($price, $currency);` code fails because the Locale object is null.

Prestashop is updated to 1.7.8.3 version.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```php
Tools::getContextLocale($this->context)->formatPrice($price, $this->context->currency->iso_code);
```